# Check if a value exist in a column and change in another Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following information.

Let's say I have the following list.

```
my_list = [2,3,4,5]
```

My dataframe is as follows:

df

```
Col1      Value
[1,3,6]    Hot
[7]        Mild
[10,11,2]  Cool
[5,9]      Cool
[2,5,6]    Mild
```

I would like to check if one of the value from the list `my_list` exist in the column `Col1`. If it exist, change the value in `Value` column to `Hot` in the corresponding row.

I would like to see something like below.

```
Col1      Value
[1,3,6]    Hot
[7]        Mild
[10,11,2]  Cool
[5,9]      Hot
[2,5,6]    Hot
```

I am just looking for a simple script that can iterate and check in every row and change a value in another column the corresponding row.

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `explode`, `isin`, `agg`, and `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Col1'].explode().isin(my_list).groupby(level=0).any(), 'Value'] = 'Hot'
```

Output:

```
>>> df
          Col1 Value
0    [1, 3, 6]   Hot
1          [7]  Mild
2  [10, 11, 2]   Hot
3       [5, 9]   Hot
4    [2, 5, 6]   Hot
```

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Hi, I have additional condition with additional column. For example, column named ```sum``` should be greater than 0 to replace the value. If you can add this, can I still edit the question?

Comment: Do you mind asking that in a new question? It's considered bad practice to edit questions in such a way as to make answers invalid.

Comment: Alright! Will do that.